# How can I export a PDF from a Word document, which contains an SVG file with a gradient?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, svg, microsoft-word-365

I am currently using Word 365, version 2207. The document I am editing contains an SVG file, which in turn contains a `<radialGradient>` element. When I import this SVG file into Word, the picture is displayed correctly, as can be seen here:

[image: SVG in Word]

However, when I export the Word file to PDF, regardless on which export settings I use (such as optimize for image quality, PDF/A compliant, etc.), the gradient disappears and is replaced by a static color, as can be seen here:

[image: SVG in PDF]

My question now is, how can I export my Word document as a PDF while retaining the gradient?

---

Please note that this question is similar to the question [Preserve SVG with gradients after PDF export from Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1604706/preserve-svg-with-gradients-after-pdf-export-from-word), but both answers to that question are specific to MacOS, which does not apply in my case, as I am running Windows.

Answer (score -1):

[According to Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-export-word-to-pdf-with-svgvectors/339dcef3-63ea-4045-bf68-de4949fcb4b9), "We now print and export SVG as vectors in PDF." A user responded, "I just updated to 1708 and it works!" *However,* other users [did not get that to work](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-export-word-to-pdf-and-maintain-the-svg/06e924a6-e91b-406f-bab8-3144191d9b07).

Some work-arounds, if updating does not help:

- Try opening the save document in free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) *Writer* and save to PDF from that application. **N.B.** Older versions of Writer [did a poor job of exporting SVG files](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96892), but hopefully, that is fixed by now.
- Convert the vector graphics to a rasterized image, such as JPG or PNG. One way to do this is:

  - Select the image in MS*Word*.
  - Copy the image to clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  - Paste the image into an editor such as free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) with its [Plugins package](https://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) (to open SVG format).
  - Save the image in JPG (or PNG) format *at your desired resolution*. Unlike the word-processing programs, this gives you a choice along the file-size/image quality spectrum.

[image: IrfanView SVG to JPG]

- Paste the saved file into *Word*, replacing the selected SVG.

  Of course, unlike a vector graphic, JPG and PNG rasterized images eventually degrade at *large* magnifications, but they can be made to look good up to a specific zoom factor.

Comment: So in short "rasterize or bust"? Because the word document I have doesn't work all too well with libre office (alignment issues, etc.)

Comment: As mentioned, MS community *claims* the vector graphics issue has been fixed in *some* version of *Word*, so you might try a different version (even an earlier one, if regression broke a fixed issue). The downside of using raster graphics is a larger file, but I find, not by much, even for *very* large dimensions, since JPG and PNG are compressed.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Word is set to update to the latest version via GPO. Rasterization to a PNG file is probably the best I can do at this point, at least until Microsoft fixes their broken SVG export code.